# Multiple outputs from wtforms flask

Tags: python, flask, wtforms

How do I get multiple outputs printed on a page from one single wtform?
So I have a form created on forms.py

```
class PostForm(Form):
    content = StringField("What's up?", validators=[DataRequired()])
    company_name = StringField("Company's Name", validators=[DataRequired()])
    job_type = SelectField('Job Type', choices=[('fulltime', 'Full Time'), ('parttime', 'Part Time'), ('contract', 'Contract'), ('internship', 'Internship')])
    country = SelectField(
        'Country', choices=[('BHR', 'Bahrain'), ('KWT', 'Kuwait'), ('OM', 'Oman'), ('QTR', 'Qatar'), ('SA', 'Saudi Arabia'), ('UAE', 'U.A.E')]
    )
    job_description = TextAreaField("Job description", validators=[DataRequired()])
    responsibilities = TextAreaField("Responsibilities the future employee will have/do.", validators=[DataRequired()])
    job_requierments = TextAreaField("Requirements that are needed for the job.", validators=[DataRequired()])
    bonus = TextAreaField("Bonus/Extras that an employee can have which makes him a better candidate for the job.", validators=[DataRequired()])
    perks = TextAreaField("Perks that the future employee can get by working with you", validators=[DataRequired()])
    about_us = TextAreaField("Abous Us (About the employer/Company)", validators=[DataRequired()])
    apply_now = TextAreaField("How to apply", validators=[DataRequired()])
    email = StringField('Your email', validators=[DataRequired(), Email()])
    mob_numb = StringField('Your phone number(s), and please only use numbers!', validators=[DataRequired()])
```

and in my models.py I got the following (note that I am doing this following an online course but I am adding and editing my own stuff that is why I don't know how to add multiple outputs from one form)

```
class Post(Model):
    timestamp = DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
    user = ForeignKeyField(
        rel_model=User,
        related_name='posts'
    )
    content = TextField()
```

and for my html file that I am outputting the form is

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block content %}

{% for post in stream %}


<h2><a href="{{ url_for('stream', username=post.user.content) }}"> {{ post.content }} </a></h2> 


{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

I get the content printed out correctly and it works great, but when I try to add for example 
country_name = TextField() under content = TextField() in models I get an error:

```
peewee.OperationalError: no such column: t1.company_name
```

and if I go to my html page and write

```
{{ form.country_name }}
```

I get the following error

```
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'form' is undefined
```

and if I use

```
post.country_name
```

nothing shows.

any ideas?

EDIT: forgot to add my app.py for the form

```
    @app.route('/new_post', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
@login_required
def post():
    form = forms.PostForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        models.Post.create(user=g.user.id,
                           content=form.content.data.strip())
        flash("Message posted! Thanks!", "success")
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    return render_template('post.html', form=form)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
peewee.OperationalError: no such column: t1.company_name
```

If you add a new field in your models.py you need to update the database table as well. This error is indicating that the model (in models.py) does not match the table in your database.

> and if I go to my html page and write

```
{{ form.country_name }}
```

> I get the following error
>
> jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'form' is undefined

In the view that is handeling your request you need to specify a form in your return. Otherwise you won't be able to access the form.

```
def page():
   myform = forms.MyForm()
   return render_template('page.html', form=myform)
```

> and if I use

```
post.country_name
```

> nothing shows.
>   any ideas?

This is hard to tell since in your html that you have pasted you are trying to loop through "stream" which is something that you are not submitting along with your html in the "post()" method that you have shown.

The code below will hopefully give you an idea on how to use a form in a webpage.

app.py

```
def page():
   myform = MyForm()
   return render_template('page.html', forminhtml=myform)
```

page.html

```
Content: {{ forminhtml.content }}
Company name: {{ forminhtml.company_name }}
```

Comment: Got it to work with your help. Thanks! What I did is I added ex: `company_name = TextField()` in my models.py and in my app.py I added `company_name=form.company_name.data.strip()` under post() and that made it work!